# React Native pass a function as props to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to pass a function from one component to its child, in this case `Posts.js` maps through each post and adds a prop called `changeState`. But It does not appear to be working.

The code for `Posts.js`

```js
import Post from "./post"

export default function posts() {

  const posts = [<arrayOfPosts>];

  const [favoritesChanged, setFavoritesChanged] = useState(1);

  const changeState = () => {
    setFavoritesChanged(Math.random());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("favorites changed");
  }, [favoritesChanged])

  return (
    {posts.map((post) => {
      <Post changeState={changeState} key={post.id} />
    }
  )
}
```

Then in the `post.js` file we have:

```js
const Post = ({ changeState }) => {
  console.log("change state: ", changeState);
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={changeState}>
        <Text>Click here to test.</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{post.title}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Post
```

But the press action doesn't fire the `changeState` function and where it is being `console.log`ged it says `undefined`. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing returning the `Post` component JSX in the `.map` callback:

```
return (
  {posts.map((post) => {
    return <Post changeState={changeState} key={post.id} post={post} />
  })}
);
```

or using an implicit arrow function return:

```
return (
  {posts.map((post) => (
    <Post changeState={changeState} key={post.id} post={post} />
  ))}
);
```

Ensure you are destructuring ***all*** the props you need that are passed:

```
const Post = ({ changeState, post }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={changeState}>
        <Text>Click here to test.</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{post.title}</Text>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Comment: thanks for your response. All of your points are valid. My questions was malformed and incomplete it appears. Strangely, it just started working and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as the return in the posts component:

```js
return (
    <>
    {
      posts.map(val => <Post changeState={changeState} key={val}/>)
    }
    </>
)
```

See this as a reference : [Sandbox reference](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-leavitt-3mcvn)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the sandbox appears to be empty.